# t-sql query returns undefined after using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working with a MS SQL database on Windows 2012 Server
I need to query only 1 column from a table that I only have access to read, not make any kind of changes.

Problem is that the name of the column is "Value"
My code is this:

```
SELECT 'Value' FROM table
```

If I add

```
`ORDER BY 'Value'`
```

The issue is that the query is returning an empty list of results.

**Things I've tried already**

- I tried replacing `'` *with* `"' but this didn't work either.
- I also tried writing `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT VALUE`
- Using the table name in the SELECT or ORDER clauses again didn't help

Comment: do not use quotes and give the exact query u are running. so not split them in pieces

Comment: An empty listing means you have no data in the table.

Comment: but when I remove the order by statement it show the results

Answer (score 2):

You are claiming that this query:

```
SELECT 'Value'
FROM table
ORDER BY 'Value'
```

Is returning no rows.  That's not quite correct.  It is returning an error because SQL Server does not allow constant expressions as keys for `ORDER BY` (or `GROUP BY` for that matter).

Do not use single quotes.  In this case:

```
SELECT 'Value' as val
FROM table
ORDER BY val;
```

Or, if `value` is a column in the table:

```
SELECT t.Value
FROM table t
ORDER BY t.Value;
```

`Value` is not a reserved word in SQL Server, but if it were, you could escape it:

```
SELECT t.[Value]
FROM table t
ORDER BY t.[Value];
```

Comment: Value is indeed the name of the column, if I use your example with t.Value it returns null and if use the example with 'Value' it returns "Value" on all rows and "val" as the name of the result column

Comment: do not use quotes. 

`SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY value`

Comment: I tried, it returns NULL for all the values and gives value as the name of the result column

Comment: provide ur column name and exact query that u wrote with order by.

Comment: I did in the question, that is the exact query

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your table has null values. and because of the order by all null values come first.

try to add filter like this

```
select Value FROM table 
where Value is not null and Value <> ''
order by Value
```